# Error connecting to MarkLogic ODBC server from pyodbc on Windows

Tags: odbc, marklogic, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to MarkLogic ODBC server using pyodbc. The connection opens fine. However, when I run a query with `cursor.execute`, I get an error,

> XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected "", expecting ""

As per MarkLogic, this might happen if client expects transaction or adds "BEGIN..." at the start. In this case, even after turning pyodbc autocommit off, the error persists.

Note that the same query works with C# DataSet code.

The SQL query is simple `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME`.

Comment: Try turning autocommit *on*,  e.g., `cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)`

Comment: autocommit=True works!

Comment: However, pyodbc fails to reflect schemas from Marklogic. This should be another question though.